# KnockoutJS - trimming whitespace on a string array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a simple situation where I want to accept an array of text, and so I let the user enter the data separated by commas, and in my KO view model I use a `ko.computed` to parse this. Code shown below. (Major thanks to RPN for showing me this trick)

## View Model

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    this.values = ko.observableArray(["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"]);

    this.computedJoinedValues = ko.computed({
        read: function() {
            return this.values().join(",");
        },
        write: function(newValue) {
            this.values(newValue.split(","));   
        },
        owner: this
    });
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

## HTML

```
<input data-bind="value: computedJoinedValues" />


<hr/>
<ul data-bind="foreach: values">
    <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

This works great - but I am having an issue with whitespace and I am having a bit of a brain disconnect. I want to trim off trailing whitespace for each entry, because I was ending up with results like `tag1, tag2`, which actually got serialized as `[ "tag1", " tag2" ]` - so I thought the appropriate place to do that was the `write` function, so I tried this...

```
write: function(newValue) {
    newValue = $.trim(newValue);
    console.log(newValue);
    this.values(newValue.split(","));   
},
```

but I am still getting spaces in the array. Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jQuery, following code will help you :

```
write: function(newValue) {
    this.values($.map(newValue.split(","), $.trim)); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to strip whitespace from inside the string - trim() just strips it from the start and end of the string:

```
write: function(newValue) {
  this.values(newValue.replace(/\s/g, '').split(","));
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't just remove all spaces like that from the string, just leading/trailing.

Comment: Why not? It's simple and fast. Unless you need spaces inside of the tokens (which are tags, which are usually required to be space-free).

Comment: Well he's trimming whitespace from the strings, not stripping it off completely. ;)

Comment: With the test data: ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"] "test1, test2, test3..." trimming and stripping are perfectly equivalent.

Comment: If array element has space inside of it, for example, 'test 1'. space between 'test' and '1' is going to be removed. That's what Jeff pointed.

Comment: Yep, I agree, which is why I said it looks like the application is for tags without spaces based on the word "tag" and the fact that all of the test data is space-free.